# Prestashop objectmodel double fields validation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have this `Artist` object model class:

```
class Artist extends ObjectModel
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $last_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $pseudonym;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $letter;

    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = [
        'table' => 'artist',
        'primary' => 'id_artist',
        'fields' => [
            'first_name' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 64],
            'last_name' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 64],
            'pseudonym' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 64],
            'letter' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 1],
        ],
    ];

    public function update($null_values = false)
    {
        $this->autoUpdateLetter();

        return parent::update(true);
    }

    public function add($auto_date = true, $null_values = false)
    {
        $this->autoUpdateLetter();

        return parent::add($auto_date, true);
    }

    private function autoUpdateLetter()
    {
        if (null === $this->letter || '' === $this->letter) {
            if (null !== $this->last_name && '' !== $this->last_name) {
                $this->letter = strtoupper($this->last_name[0]);
            } elseif (null !== $this->pseudonym && '' !== $this->pseudonym) {
                $this->letter = strtoupper($this->pseudonym[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the admin `CRUD` system, I want `last_name` OR `pseudonym` to be required but not necessary both.

I know how to set a required field one by one, but I'm stuck for global object validation.

What is the best way?

Comment: I guess both have to be not required and all needed verification need to be done in biz.logic. You can check how to works "phones" fields in Address class, there is only 1 hone required

Comment: That's a clue, but I didn't find any validation process under `Address` class. Could you please tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this both field to required=>false and validate these fields in postProcess function in admin controller you are using for CRUD.

In postProcess before calling parent::postProcess you can validate either of these fields and set error respectively.

Hope this helps;)

Comment: If I override `postProcess`, I have to re-do the hole try/catch logic inside it. I'm not sure it's the best way. But I saw some hook executions, maybe here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way thanks to Sergii P and Divyesh P clues.

You have a `_childValidation` method called by `validateRules` from `AdminController`. This method is specific for custom validations.

So here is my working code under `AdminArtistsController`:

```
public function _childValidation()
{
    $object = new Artist();

    if ('' === Tools::getValue('last_name') && '' === Tools::getValue('pseudonym')) {
        $this->errors[] = sprintf(
            Tools::displayError('You have to fill at least %1$s or %2$s field.'),
            $object->displayFieldName('last_name', Artist::class),
            $object->displayFieldName('pseudonym', Artist::class)
        );
    }
}
```

I'd like to have this logic under the `Artist` class but I don't know if it's really possible.

Don't hesitate to tell me if you have a better / proper solution!